# Haskell#splitAt

Tags: haskell, reinventing-the-wheel

Here's how I wrote the Haskell `splitAt` function:

```
splitAt' :: Int -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
splitAt' n ys 
      | n < 0     = ([], ys)
      | otherwise = splitAt'' n ys []
      where splitAt'' a (x:xs) acc
                  | a == 0 = (acc, x:xs)
                  | null xs = (acc ++ [x], [])
                  | otherwise = splitAt'' (a-1) xs (acc ++ [x])
```

I don't like I'm using the append (`++`) function to add an element to the end of my `acc(umulator)`.

But, given the importance of ordering, I'm not sure how to avoid using it.

Please review this code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to implement it without `++`.

```
splitAt' :: Int -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
splitAt' 0 ys     = ([], ys)
splitAt' _ []     = ([], [])
splitAt' n (y:ys)
  | n < 0     = ([], (y:ys))
  | otherwise = ((y:a), b)
  where (a, b) = splitAt' (n - 1) ys
```

Comment: Hi @200_success. Re: negatives aren't allowed: `*Main> splitAt (-3) "heyman"` produces `("","heyman")` using GHCI 7.6.3. Also, with your above function, using a negative won't produce an error. It'll simply put the entire list in the first part of the tuple, leaving `[]` for the second part. Example: `*Main> splitAt' (-3) [1..100]` produces `([1,...,100],[])`

Comment: You're right! I've added a case to handle negative `n`.

Comment: Thanks!  Out of curiosity,  when do you use the "don't care" (`_`) for arguments? Example: `splitAt' n []` but n isn't used so why not use don't care? Maybe there's a general style rule?

Comment: Right again! The "don't care" placeholder should be used whenever possible. I've edited that in.